# Laravel: How to restrict route to admin and groupmates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am currently developing a website using Laravel.
A user belongs to 1 and only 1 group.
How do I restrict the route

```
Route::('/view/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@showProfile');
```

to be only accessible by other users belonging to the same group. I would also like to allow the admin to access this route. However the admin does not belong to any group.

Comment: You can use [acl](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/), it's a role-based permissions system for Laravel 5 that can help you do exactly what you asked for, with role and permission. Give it a try !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there are two ways to solve your problem.

1. You can create a custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) and [bind](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-middleware) it to your route.
2. Or you can do a simple check in your controller method.

I will give an example of the second method since it is the easiest.

Example:

```
// YourController.php

public function yourMethod()
{

    // Get the user from authentication
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Check user and redirect to login when NULL
    // This also can be done with auth middleware (check link in method 1)
    if (!$user) return Response::redirect('yourLoginRoute');

    // Check if has not group throw forbidden
    if ($user->group->id != theGroupId) return App::abort(403);

}
```

**Edit after comment @PaulLucero**

So if I understand correctly only users of the same group can visit eachothers profile page (view/profile/{id}). Also you want to use a middleware to solve this problem but are unable to retrieve the route parameter {id}.

You can retrieve a parameter in Laravel 4 outside a route by using `Route::input('yourParameter')`. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) and scroll down to **Accessing A Route Parameter Value**.

Example:

```
class YourMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        // Get id from route and get user model
        $user_id = Route::input('id');

        $user = User::find($user_id);

        // Do some checks
        ....

        // Get user from auth
        $auth_user = Auth::user();

        // Do some checks
        ....

        // If groups don't match throw 403
        if ($user->group_id != $auth_user->group_id) return App::abort(403);

        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: I would like to use a middleware. However I don't know how to check the requested user's (via {id}) group against the group of the authenticated user. I am aware of the method handle($request, Closure $next) but I don't know how to write the code for checking.

Comment: In the user table, there is a group_id column, since it is only one to many relationship, I did not bother to use a pivot table. So the user's group is accessible by $user->group_id.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom middleware  try like this

```
public function yourMethod()
        {
           $user = Auth::user();
           if ($user->group_id == 1) {
              return Response::redirect('yourRouteToGroupID-1');
           else if(if ($user->group_id == 2) {)
              return Response::redirect('yourRouteToGroupID-2');
           else{
              return App::abort(403);
           }
         }
```